# Subset data by distinct variables (multiple times)

Tags: r, subset

I have a dataset with ten countries denoted by country codes. I want a subset for each country. This works, but I wonder whether there is a quicker way:

```
France <- subset(data, Country == 100)
Britain <- subset(data, Country == 101)
Italy <- subset(data, Country == 102)
```

...

What I want is to create ten datasets based on the value of the variable Country. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Leo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do `split` and keep it in a list

```
lst <- setNames(split(data, data$Country), c("France", "Britain", "Italy"))
list2env(lst, .GlobalEnv)

France
```

Comment: Thank you very much, akrun! I'm almost there now - great help! Any way, though, to create a dataframe with the individual country names. Right now I added a "countries <- setNames(spilt...)" and by "France <- countries$France" I created the dataframe. Do you know how to make them a dataframe straight away? Cheers!   PS: For other users: a bracket's missing in akrun's code.. :-)

Comment: Absolute legend, akrun! Thanks a lot - and I'll provide examples in future... :-)

Comment: @LeoModest  Though, I would recommend to do the operations inside the list itself rather than splitting up into individual datasets unless you are doing different operations for each dataset.  If it is to save the datasets to multiple files, you can still use `lapply(lst, function(x) write.table(....))`